# Symfony 3 handle multiple langages with their URLs

Tags: php, symfony

Hi I'm trying to add multiple langages support into my symfony app since 3 days without success.

I want handle URLS depending on user's locale preference and add link to switch langage when not logged in.

Every things I tried didn't work I guess I'm doing something wrong.

I want mange two langages French and English.
`myapp.com/fr/contactez-nous` and `myapp.com/en/contact-us`for example.

***app/config/config.yml***

```
parameters:
    locale: fr
framework:
    translator: { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
    default_locale: '%locale%'
```

***app/config/routing.yml***

```
locale:
    resource: "@StandardBundle/Controller/"
    type: annotation
    requirements:
        _locale: fr|en
    defaults:  { _locale: '%locale%' }
```

***Controller***

```
/**
 * @Route("/{_locale}/contactez-nous", name="contact_fr")
 * @Route("/{_locale}/contact-us", name="contact_en")
 */
public function contactAction(){
}
```

It works as expected even langage switching using this into my twig's view

```
{% if app.request.locale == "en" %}
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), 
    app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'fr'})) }}">Français</a>
{% else %}
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), 
    app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'en'})) }}">English</a>
{% endif %}
```

Everything is fine, but when I'm log in with an user which locale is `en`, symfony doesn't apply any changes.

Here is how my user is logged in

***app/config/security.yml***

```
firewalls:
    main:
    pattern: ^/
        anonymous: true
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - guardAuthenticator
```

***src/MyBundle/Ressources/config/services.yml***

```
services:
    guardAuthenticator:
        class: MyBundle\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
        autowire: true
```

***MyBundle\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator***

```
class LoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator
{
    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        $user = $token->getUser();
        $idUtil = $user->getId();
        $session->set('_locale', $user->getLocale());
        /*
         * ALSO TRIED THIS
         * but after logged in request is not updated :(
        /*
        $request->setLocale($user->getLocale());
        $session->set('_security_main', serialize($token));
        $session->save();
    }
}
```

I tried this [Making the Locale "Sticky" during a User's Session](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/session/locale_sticky_session.html#setting-the-locale-based-on-the-user-s-preferences) and many other solutions found accross google without success.

And when I'm log out, I'm redirect here

[image]

not to `myapp.com/app_dev.php/fr` whit associate controller

```
/**
 * @Route("/{_locale}/", name="home")
 */
public function HomeAction()
{
}
```

I have to enter locale in the adresse bar manually.

I will realy appreciate any help onto this it start to make me really crazy for something so simple in without framework thank you

Comment: Hi, you might find helful resources in this blog post: https://www.strangebuzz.com/en/blog/implement-a-read-in-your-language-link-with-symfony

Comment: Why Symfony 3.4? The last version is 5.0.

Comment: @COil I saw that link too, but I want to learn symfony mechanics I'm pretty sure there is a way to do thtat without extra bundle.

Comment: @COil true but what if I learn SF 5 and client ask for project using 3.4 because he doesn't take time yet to migrate to latest ? I will do nothing

Comment: The i18n handling is better because you don't have to declare one route for each language. I was asking because if it's a new project there no reason to start at least with 4.4. May be you test on a new project and instead of the real one?

Comment: If the only interest is to not declare one route for each languages, you have to know that I have only 5 routes in my project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207352/discussion-between-akio-and-coil).